# Como acessar um objeto no qual a chave é um número?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho um objeto cujo a chave de uma propriedade é um número, não consigo acessar esse dado utilizando `dados.1.TIPOPROCEDIMENTO`. Como posso fazer isso?

```js
const dados = {
  "1": {
    "TIPOPROCEDIMENTO": "Humanas",
    "DESCRICAO": "Trabalhe%20com%20a%20Ema",
  },
  "2": {
    "TIPOPROCEDIMENTO": "Uniema",
    "DESCRICAO": "Solicita%E7%E3o%20de%20usu%E1rio%20AVE",
  }
}

console.log(dados.1.TIPOPROCEDIMENTO)
```

Answer (score 3):

A resposta para seu problema é bem simples, basta você trocar a maneira como estava fazendo:

```
dados.1.TIPOPROCEDIMENTO
```

Por:

```
dados['1']['TIPOPROCEDIMENTO']
```

Veja na prática:

```js
const dados = {
  "1": {
    "TIPOPROCEDIMENTO": "Humanas",
    "DESCRICAO": "Trabalhe%20com%20a%20Ema",
  },
  "2": {
    "TIPOPROCEDIMENTO": "Uniema",
    "DESCRICAO": "Solicita%E7%E3o%20de%20usu%E1rio%20AVE",
  }
}

console.log(dados['1']['TIPOPROCEDIMENTO'])
```

[Exemplo de teste no React Native](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/dGVzdG) (questionado originalmente na pergunta)